# Spring boot MockMVC test not using custom gson type mapper for deserialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, gson

I have the following type mapper:

```
public class LocaleTwoWaySerializer implements JsonSerializer<Locale>, JsonDeserializer<Locale> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final Locale src, final Type typeOfSrc, final JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return src == null ? JsonNull.INSTANCE : new JsonPrimitive(src.getLanguage());
    }

    @Override
    public Locale deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return json == null || JsonNull.INSTANCE.equals(json) ? null : new Locale(json.getAsString());
    }
}
```

My GsonConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class GsonConfig {

    private static Gson GSON = generateStaticBuilder().create();


    private static GsonBuilder generateStaticBuilder() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                                    .registerTypeAdapter(Locale.class, new LocaleTwoWaySerializer())
                                    .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
                                    .setPrettyPrinting()
    }


    @Bean
    public Gson getGsonInstance() {
        return GSON;
    }


}
```

My Web Config:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @Autowired
    public GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter(final Gson gson) {
        GsonHttpMessageConverter converter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setGson(gson);
        return converter;
    }

}
```

My Test:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK    )
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyTestClassIT {


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    @Test
    public void updateLocale() throws Exception {
        Locale locale = Locale.ITALIAN;
        mvc.perform(patch("/mypath").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(gson.toJson(locale))).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

The api i am testing has this signature:

```
@PatchMapping(path = "myPath")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> updateLocale(@RequestBody Locale preferredLocale)
```

I have placed breakpoints and can verify that my GsonHttpMessageConverter is being constructed, and serialization in my test using the autowired GSON instance directly works fine (using my typeAdapter) 
however I am getting a 400 bad request,  As the type adapter is not used to deserialize.

What is missing please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not getting a `404` instead? I recreated your project here https://github.com/Flaw101/gsonconverter and verified it was working except with your setup it's a `404` because of capitalization in the `path` param which is not in the test.

```
  mvc.perform(patch("/mypath").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(gson.toJson(locale))).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

should be

```
  mvc.perform(patch("/myPath").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(gson.toJson(locale))).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: that's merely a typo in my question when i was simplifying my example. definitely a 400 due to data serialization

Comment: Can you post your POM?